# VSTS Extension: "Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: appdirectory webappname ResourceGroupName"

Tags: azure, powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on creating a VSTS task for a release and am getting the above error. I know what the error means, but I am not sure how to resolve as this is the first time I am creating a custom task.

Essentially the task takes a source file and FTP's it up to Azure, based on published profile settings it attains within the script.

Here is the PowerShell code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation $MyInvocation

$appdirectory = get-vstsinput -Name appdirectory
$webappname = get-vstsinput -Name webappname
$ResourceGroupName = get-vstsinput -Name ResourceGroupName

#write-host $appdirectory

$location="East US"
    try {
    # Get inputs.
    # Get publishing profile for the web app
    $xml = [xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -OutputFile null)

    # Extracts connection information from publishing profile
    $username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
    $password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
    $url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

    Write-Output "$username"
    Write-Output "$password"
    Write-Output "$url"
    #Write-Output "$localpath"

    # Upload files recursively
    Set-Location $appdirectory
    $webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
        $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
        "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
        $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
    }
    $webclient.Dispose()

    } finally {
        Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation $MyInvocation
    }
```

Associated with this is a JSON file that is used for the build and the release manager within TFS. Here is the code for that:

```
    {
    "id": "LongStringofNumbers",
    "name": "NameOfTask",
    "friendlyName": "FriendlyNameOfTask",
    "description": "Build Task that will upload a file or folder to a destination in Azure using Published Profile Credentials.",
    "helpMarkDown": "",
    "category": "Build",
    "visibility": [
        "Build"
    ],
    "runsOn": [
        "Agent",
        "DeploymentGroup"
    ],
    "author": "ME",
    "version": {
        "Major": 0,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Patch": 16
    },
    "instanceNameFormat": "Uploads File Using Published Profile Credentials",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "advanced",
            "displayName": "Advanced",
            "isExpanded": true
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "appdirectory",
            "type": "filePath",
            "label": "Source Path",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Location of file(s) for uploading to Azure."
        },
        {
            "name": "webappname",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Azure Webapp name",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Azure App name; I.E. - 900014campuslinkapi."
        },
        {
            "name": "ResourceGroupName",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Azure Resource Group name",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Azure Resource Group Name I.E. - 900014-prod."
        }
    ],
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell3": {
            "target": "powershell.ps1",
            "platforms": [
                "windows"
            ],
            "argumentFormat": "",
            "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
        }
    }
}
```

So the error is stating I need the three mandatory parameters which from the JSON file is added as a field in the release manager. But I don't think the script and the JSON file are connecting for some reason so even when I place in items in the release manager fields, it still fails with the error. Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: but are you passing anything to those parameters? it says `defaultValue = ''`

Comment: @4c74356b41 That's kind of where I am unsure. I am basing some of this off of an already functioning FTP extension called FTP Uploader (it is in the marketplace - code available) which has the same json file essentially with nothing in the default value for it so I don't think that is the show stopper but I am unsure exactly. The parameters are being put into the release manager but for some reason, when it executes it isn't being picked up and that's what I am missing. The connection between what I'm putting in release manager and how the script picks up those values.

Comment: @DangeRuss Can you share the entire extension in one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT you can download the project here: [download](http://www.russmittler.com/Downloads/FTP_Task_v2.zip)

Comment: @DangeRuss Since the task using PowerShell instead of Azure PowerShell, you need additional parameters for login Azure. Besides in your task, you upload files vis FTP, you'd better give the option to specify FTP server in the task configuration.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I don't agree with that... The script works fine when running as a script, even being regular PowerShell; to resolve this temporarily I created an inline script using the same parameters and it works fine. The error isn't the process itself but that the script isn't connecting to the VSTS inputs. I modified the script to use get-vstsinputs function but I am still getting the error. Now instead of making the parameters required in the original script, I am using the following: `$appdirectory = get-vstsinput -Name appdirectory` I am still getting the same error tho.

Comment: Do you mean the script works if you run it manually but does not work when run as build task?

Answer (score 0):

You still have to pull the values into your script. Look at how the [reference tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) function, or look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib).

Your script needs to import and use the task SDK and call [`Get-VstsInput`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Commands.md#get-vstsinput) to retrieve the values.

For what it's worth, you should use the `PowerShell3` handler, as `PowerShell` is legacy.

Another option is to not create a custom task if this is intended only for internal use, although 100% bias on my part. I dislike turning simple PowerShell scripts into opaque black boxes and prefer to drive everything from source control.

Comment: while I agree with you regarding just using this as a script, it is not the ask of my current employ. I can make it work fine as a script, but building it as a task is where I am stuck. But the documentation is pointing me in the right direction. I guess I am confused because I am basing a lot of what I am doing on a current task called [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task); this task doesn't seem to make use of get-vstsinput (at least not that I could find when digging through the code).

Comment: I modified the script with the use of get-vstsinput but am still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to remove the mandatory parameters. Parameters come into the script via `Get-VstsInput`, not via a `param` block.

Comment: Right, if you check the script above, I edited it to the way it is now which I removed the param block and used `$appdirectory = get-vstsinput -Name appdirectory` instead. I rebuilt/redeployed the task but still get the same error when it runs. Do you think its possible that remnants of the old task are not being cleared out? Its strange I get the same behavior when I don't even have a param block with requirements any longer.

Comment: Did you bump the tasks version number?

Comment: Yeah, its up a version number. I leave the old builds in the folder so I don't forget to do that so if I didn't, it would fail. I am going to try something and see if this works.